# Fourier Transform of $x^{-2}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I get that the integral $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} t^{-2} e^{i\omega t} dt $ is not convergent, since there is a singularity at $t =0$.

However, I know (Wolfram) that Fourier transform of $f(x) = t^{-2}$ is:

$ g(\omega)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\omega$

Can somebody explain how is this possible?

Comment: $-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\omega|$ is the principal value of an integral. Principal values extend the usual concept of convergence, allowing us to compute the Fourier transforms of functions that do not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ or $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value